# How to filter a range in comparison to phrase using elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to search an index for a hits that are more or equal to some phrase. To be more clear I need to build query like the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE MyNVarCharField >= 'some_string'
```

Mapping:

```
{
    "tock": {
        "mappings": {
            "post": {
                "properties": {
                    "content": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index_analyzer": "english"
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "double"
                    },
                    "title": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index_analyzer": "english"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Index contains two objects:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Post1",
        "content": "Ash to ash item"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Post2",
        "content": "Dust to dust item"
    }
]
```

Now I want to search for an objects which content is greater or equal to "*Dust to dust item*". I tried many different approaches and ended up with something like that:

```
{
    "sort": [
        {
            "content": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ],
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "match": {
                "content": {
                    "query": "item"
                }
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "range": {
                "content": {
                    "from": "Dust to dust",
                    "include_lower": true,
                    "include_upper": true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work as I expect. Both objects are returned. So I need help :)

Is it really possible to query elastic in such manner? What I need to do to split index in two parts by a phrase?

By the way, you should mention that it is guaranteed that this phrase already exists in the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your range filter matches both documents because the text is compared to each of the terms generated for the `"content"` field, not against the raw source text. Since the [`english` analyzer](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#english-analyzer) uses the [standard tokenizer](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html), one of these terms, for each document, is `"item"`. Since `"item"` is greater than `"dust"`, both documents match.

If you have very many documents in your index, the approach you are using is probably not going to be workable because so many terms are going to be generated.

One thing you can do is use the setting `"index":"not_analyzed"` on your `"content"` field. Or, if you need `"content"` to be analyzed for other reasons, then define a [sub-field](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html) that isn't analyzed, then do your range comparison against that field. Here is an example.

So I defined an index as follows:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "mappings": {
      "post": {
         "properties": {
            "content": {
               "type": "string",
               "index_analyzer": "english",
               "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "index": "not_analyzed"
                  }
               }
            },
            "id": {
               "type": "double"
            },
            "title": {
               "type": "string",
               "index_analyzer": "english"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then added three docs (your two plus another for comparison):

```
POST /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"post","_id":1}}
{"id": 1,"title": "Post1", "content": "Ash to ash item"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"post","_id":2}}
{"id": 2,"title": "Post2", "content": "Dust to dust item"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"post","_id":3}}
{"id": 3,"title": "Post3", "content": "Earth to earth item"}
```

Then I can use a range query against `"content.raw"`:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "range": {
           "content.raw": {
              "gte": "Dust to dust"
           }
        }
    }
}
```

and it returns what I expect:

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "post",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "id": 2,
               "title": "Post2",
               "content": "Dust to dust item"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "post",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "id": 3,
               "title": "Post3",
               "content": "Earth to earth item"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

**Edit:** You can adapt the query you posted by changing `"content"` to `"content.raw"` (also your syntax was slightly wrong and gave me an error, so I wrapped the query and filter in a `"query"` block):

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "sort": [
      {
         "content": {
            "order": "asc"
         }
      }
   ],
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match": {
               "content": {
                  "query": "item"
               }
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "range": {
               "content.raw": {
                  "from": "Dust to dust",
                  "include_lower": true,
                  "include_upper": true
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "post",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "id": 2,
               "title": "Post2",
               "content": "Dust to dust item"
            },
            "sort": [
               "dust"
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "post",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "id": 3,
               "title": "Post3",
               "content": "Earth to earth item"
            },
            "sort": [
               "earth"
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is the code I used for testing:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/57968fda91b9bcd5b2f1d8236ecb5fc1953800b7

Comment: Oh, I knew I should give more attention to multi-fields. Also thank you for sense.qbox link.